VSCode Terminal is bugging out while locally hosting my website with GET and POST Packages
Here's a link to a video I screen recorded of it. I tried disabling all Extensions and restarting VSCode. I'm really not sure what else to try.
GET and POST Packages would just immediately start cluttering my terminal as soon as I start up my website locally with the 'npm run dev' command.
Help would be greatly greatly appreciated!

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
